# allocate memory for string in C

Tags: c, string, char, malloc

I just started C programming and I have a beginner question:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
char *a=malloc(1*sizeof(char));
a[0]='a';
a[1]='b';
a[2]='c';
printf("%c\n",a[0]);
printf("%c\n",a[1]);
printf("%c\n",a[2]);
printf("%s\n",a);
return 0;
}
```

So I would like to create a String consist of unknown length of word by entering character one by one. Because I won't know the length of the word so I just use malloc. I plan to allocate memory for once character first, then use reallocate to add a new space for the next character when I enter the new character. However after I malloc (1*sizeof(char)),which should only be the size of one character, I found out that I can add multiple character to the string already, why is that happening? what's the correct way to do it?

Thank everyone for your time to read through my long question :)

Comment: *"why is that happening?"* - Because undefined behavior is magic

Comment: Your code has a bug, so it won't behave as you expect. Just fix the bug. You have a long way to go before you can precisely understand complex failure modes of buggy code. So just avoid bugs for now.

Comment: *Often* - you cannot rely on that and you **totally shouldn't** - the memory manager will allocate memory in chunks larger than what you requested. So you can write in an area of memory that was not reported to you as available, and yet, it is. Of course that area might be used later on, so what you wrote there could be lost. Or changed utterly. Or you might be overwriting some important data used by the memory manager itself. In short, **just because you can do something, it doesn't mean you should**.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is redundant and unnecessary.

Comment: Thank everyone for your answers! I didn't understand the undefined behavior and i do now!

Comment: @FiddingBits Hi,so instead of sizeof(char) I can just allocate 1 byte by malloc(1) right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By "why is that happening" you mean,

- why is it *allowed*?
- why is it not "punished" (i.e., an immediate crash)?

It is allowed because C accesses memory directly; that's part of its power. Very few checks are made on what you're trying to do before letting you *do* it. That's why you need to be careful.

Why is it not "punished" with a crash, not immediately, *perhaps* not ever? Because there is not always a prohibition against writing in that region (memory protection is page-oriented). Let's say that when you allocate a memory region, it is divided in pages of 1000 bytes. Then if you allocate 50 bytes, the underlying hardware will unlock 1000 bytes. It can't unlock a smaller region. So you "can" write to all of those 1000 bytes without causing a protection fault.

Now the memory manager has to keep track of where the data *is*, so it has its own structures and it, too, often "pages" memory. So when you request 50 bytes, the software memory manager might actually allocate 256. Then if you realloc() those 50 bytes to 100, you'll see that the pointer did not change. If you realloc() those to 257 bytes, the pointer *does* change - the memory manager cannot enlarge that block to 257 bytes, so it marks it free, and allocates from the hardware a 512 block somewhere else. If you then alloc() 42 bytes, you might discover that its pointer is the same address that previously pointed to your 100-byte buffer.

Sometimes, some debug libraries will not only allocate an area but also "guard" it with canaries. You ask 50 bytes, the library allocates 66 and returns a pointer 8 bytes inside those 66. And it fills the first 8 and the last 8 bytes with a known value. Every now and then it will check that the value is still there; if it isn't, a soft crash is raised to warn you that you overflowed (or underflowed) the buffer.

In your example there is no such protection and you can write in the extra area beyond what you allocated. But chances are that area will be used later on, and overwritten: **maybe**, if you do

```
foo = malloc(20);
strcpy(foo, "string ... 30 bytes long");
bar = malloc(20); //     ^20th byte
strcpy(bar, "hello world");
```

and then print foo, you get "string ... 3hello world". Or "string ...[GARBAGE]hello world". By writing bar, which followed foo, you overwrote the area where you had stored your data.

And then again, if you never write anything into *bar*, the program might work and never complain.

Then you compile on a different platform or with a different library, and a program that had worked for years suddenly crashes. Welcome to the world of **undefined behaviour**.

Several libraries and tools are available to armor against this kind of issues - a very good tool is [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

## "Deleting" the string and/or freeing its memory

```
// I initialize the pointer to NULL. If I just declared the pointer,
// its initial value might be anything. This way, I reduce the random
// element in my program. Makes no difference... except that one time
// when it does, and will save your bacon.
char *pwd = NULL;

// Every malloc and realloc MUST check that it did not return NULL,
// meaning an error occurred. Even for small memory blocks.
if (NULL === (pwd = malloc(200))) {
     // Handle out of memory error
}
strcpy(pwd, "Squeamish Ossifrage"):

// ... do something with pwd

// ...we're done. If we just freed this area, its contents would remain
// available *and* the pointer would still point to it. so this works:
/*
      free(pwd);
      printf("The secret word is %s\n", pwd);
      ...but might explode at any moment.
*/
// pwd contains sensitive data, so we first zero it, and this requires
// remembering the actual size of the allocated block. Here, 200.
memset(pwd, 0, 200);

// Now we free the area pointed to by the pointer. Then we also
// erase the pointer.
free(pwd); pwd = NULL;
```

By writing free and NULL on the same line, I can run

```
grep 'free\\s*(' | grep -v "NULL;"
```

and find all lines where a free() has no NULL assignment, and mark those lines as potentially needing improvement.

Now if I use pwd after freeing it, it will NEVER work, which removes further randomness from the execution.

Comment: Great answer! That was really helpful, thanks!

Comment: Hi, so if I want to "empty" the string and put other unknown length of characters into the string, before I realloc the memory of the string to "1 char""2char", so on and so forth, should I call memset to set them all to 0 or just free them?

Comment: You first realloc with the new length, then rewrite. To erase the string (eg a password ) you first memset, then free. I'll update my answer later.

Comment: OK, that answered my question, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

This is happening because you're allowed to do it, but it's undefined behavior. This is called a buffer overflow, and it's a dangerous programming situation. You should allocate more memory than 1 byte, and keep track of the length of the string. Once you reach the end of your allocated space, you can call `realloc` to re allocate your memory block to a bigger size.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(/*dont write what you dont         use*/)
{ 
char *a=malloc(4/*at least*/*sizeof(char));
a[0]='a';
a[1]='b';
a[2]='c';
a[3]='\0';
//or strcpy(a, "abc");
printf("%c\n",a[0]);
printf("%c\n",a[1]);
printf("%c\n",a[2]);
printf("%s\n",a);
free(a);
return 0;
}
```

remember: when you write "?" the compiler gets

{?, '\0'}

'\0' is the end-of-string char.

Comment: Hi, so if I want to "empty" the string and put other unknown length of characters into the string, before I realloc the memory of the string to "1 char""2char", so on and so forth, should I call memset to set them all to 0 or just free them?

Comment: when you free them they will be lost forever.  you dont need to do them anything before.

Comment: ***suggest***: `a=NULL;`

Comment: after free     .......